# Does the use of multiplication by juxtaposition imply the use of parenthesis for the order of operations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

In the [section on precedence in this article](https://abstractmath.org/MM/MMSymLang.htm#subexpression) the author writes that the precedence of multiplication over addition is the reason that $xy+z$ is $(xy)+z$ and not $x(y+z)$,and I do not understand why, I was always taught that the fact that $xy$ is a juxtaposed term implies that we can see it as having a parenthesis around it to avoid confusion, and in this case it would make no difference, why does the precedence of multiplication make a difference here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Even if you write multiplication a different way (e.g. $x \cdot y + z$) then it is still interpreted $(x \cdot y) + z$ because multiplication has precedence.

Comment: I do not understand your question either.  $xy+z$ is equal to $(x\cdot y)+z$.  That should be the end of the story right there.  There is no other way in which this should be interpreted.  Why is it interpreted that way?  Because having an agreed upon manner in which we interpret things is necessary for people to be able to communicate with one another through an established language, whether that be a language like English or the language of mathematics.

Comment: @Ted if we can simply define that $xy+z$ means that $(xy)+z$ could be done if addition has precedence by using the parenthesis, how else could we interpret this if addition had precedence?

Comment: @JMoravitz so if addition has precedence, if I define that juxtaposing $xy$ means there is a parenthesis around them, then we will get the same answer, if it wasn't the case that we assume the parenthesis to be there, and addition had precedence only then could we get another answer, this is obviously different to what I've been taught.

Answer (score 1):

The reason someone might say that "a juxtaposed term implies that we can see it as having a parenthesis around it" is precisely **because** multiplication has precedence over addition. There is no other possible justification for such a statement.

In fact, the rule about "having a parenthesis around it" is not the best rule: for example, if we write $2x^2,$ then $2$ is juxtaposed with $x$, but $2x^2$ is **not** the same as $(2x)^2,$ rather, $2x^2 = 2(x^2).$ That's because exponentiation has precedence over multiplication.

I don't know where it is common to teach that "a juxtaposed term implies that we can see it as having a parenthesis around it", but it would be best to regard that as merely a teaching aid for beginning mathematics students and not as an actual mathematical rule. "Multiplication takes precedence over addition" is the actual rule.

Answer (score 0):

You have two very common conventions here.

**Multiplication has precedence over addition**

I would not dare to say that this is universal as there is no governing body setting the rules for mathematics.  You could choose to change this rule but if you do then give your readers a very clear warning as it would be very unusual.

**Multiplication is indicated by juxtaposition**

Also very common but slightky less so.  Sometimes, multiplication is explicitly indicated e.g. $x \times y$.  This is common with constants as $23$ would be a confusing way to write $2 \times 3$.  When only integers are under consideration then dot is common e.g. $12 = 2 . 2 . 3$.  In computing, $2 * 3$ is common but it is not common in mathematics.

I don't think that the two are linked.  The precedence of multiplcation over addition is usual even when juxtaposition is not used.

If you chose to give addition precedence over multiplcation then avoiding juxtaposition for multiplication may help but, as I said above, give your readers a very clear warning as this is so unusual.

**Alternatives**

There are some alternatives e.g. [Polish notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) or [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). An interesting feature of these notations is that they do not need precedence rules or parentheses.  RPN was used by some early calculators.